# Is there a specific design pattern to help manage external connection and concurrent requests?

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns

I am currently working using an external API for a web application. When the user clicks on a button, I open the connection, make the appropriate calls and then close the connection. This works fine, however, in a multi-threaded web environment, when there are two simultaneous clicks, the application crashes... this is due from the close connection being called consecutively.

Ideally, I would like to open a connection on the first request and then make all calls.. if a concurrent request comes in, and it sees there is an open connection, then it should use it.. the connection should then only be closed if there are no requests currently processing.

I started working on some code to achieve what I want, but I wanted to know if there was a specific design pattern that anyone knew of to solve this problem, or if anybody had any suggestions.. thanks!!

Comment: What programming language and platform you use? I believe most platforms support connection pooling - what do you mean by "connection" is it an application session?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov, I am using C# and ASP .NET MVC3. I am using some third party libraries, that essentially have 3 commands: 1.ConnectSocket, 2.TransferData, 3. DisconnectSocket... by connection, I meant the third parties APIs to open a socket connection.. So the problem lies in that the 3rd party libraries crash when DisconnectSocket is called consecutively which is a problem I am seeing in a multi threaded setting... like a web application.

Comment: My first idea would be connection pool plus command pattern

Comment: Cant you just check if the connection is "not closed" before calling `DisconnectSocket`? Also are you sure this connection is thread safe?

Comment: In a multi-threaded setup I would consider using a queue and message based setup to completely abstract your application away from the underlying data store and allow you to scale up easier.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for [locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
I don't know of a fitting pattern on the top of my head.

Comment: Wouldn't locking block other requests?

Comment: @Ramunas Yes. That way you can keep count of how many connections you have.

Answer (score 0):

1- how costly is to make new connection for each request?

2-Is there any guidelines issued by the library authors to limit the no of connections? 
    if no then it would be really helpful by not introducing locking in your design or multi threading at all.

This is the initial questions i asked to myself before diving into multithreaded scenario.

Also in the situation you explained above , you can never determine when the next request comes so if you are using single object of the class then it would be helpful to use double checking locking technique as explained in the wikipedia

[Double Check Locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)

Comment: +1 for the "costly"-question.  If we're talking sqlserver connections they are already pooled.